# firebase complains about database being in a different region, but database is at the correct region

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Just started with Firebase. I do basic operations and get this error:

*pRTLPCB(0,[{"t":"c","d":{"t":"s","d":"Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to https://firelab-2c0f1-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app"}}]);*

But the database **is** exactly at this url !? What could be the problem?

**Warning about the closing: The other question would never have answered this question. See my comment below: The error message is simply nonsense, do not get confused by it.**

My answer: After a while I realized that after creating the database, the configuration for the web app included a new string for the database. adding that made it working. so the problem here is a very misleading nonsensical error message that points into a wrong direction of problem hunting. firebase is not well done, at all ends, concepts, docu, implementation.

Comment: It's hard to be certain where this comes from without seeing a reproduction, or at the very least knowing what platform you use Firebase from. But I answered questions about this error message a few times before, so I recommend checking out: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%20Database%20lives%20in%20a%20different%20region.

Comment: After a while I realized that after creating the database, the configuration for the web app included a new string for the database. adding that made it working. so the problem here is a very misleading nonsensical error message that points into a wrong direction of problem hunting. firebase is not well done, at all ends, concepts, docu, implementation.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - your answers do not answer this question.

Comment: In that case I recommend writing a self-answer about what the problem was, and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I realized that after creating the database, the configuration for the web app included a new string for the database. Adding that made it working. So the problem here is a misleading error message that points into a wrong direction of problem hunting.